# what features should be implemented into the 'proper' IoC container?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I really tried to collect, what kind of features should be available in 'proper' IoC Container. And I could not found ;(

Is there any definition, source, where I can get such information ? 
It's not for the sake of argument. I just want to read somewhere strict set of rules, which determine that something might be called IoC container and something not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, abstractly speaking, IoC container should allow you to resolve 'something' from it, automatically resolving all dependencies of that 'something'.

But current IoC containers can do much more than that.

Comment: @user1016265 Yes. If you inject MyService into something, all its dependencies should be resolved automatically. Where it is possible of course.